# Rails 3 mailer issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I'm following this railscast to become familiar with ActionMailer in rails 3, but am having no luck with getting the email to deliver.

I'm thinking my issue may be with my setup_mail.rb file, can anybody spot a problem here? I'm trying to get am email to send from my gmail account jbdyno@gmail.com

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "jbdyno",
  :password             => "I PUT MY PASSWORD HERE",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

---

Other files

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "jbdyno@gmail.com"

  def registration_confirmation(user)
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")
  end

end
```

registration_confirmation.text.erb

```
Thanks for registering!
```

users_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What you did looks fine on first sight. Do you get any delivery errors or any hints in your log on what might be happening?

Comment: Did you set `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp` in the environment you are trying to send your emails from? (see the Rails Guides [on Actionmailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail) with specific settings for gmail).

Comment: On a sidenote: For getting emails displayed in development there's a great gem, [**letter_opener**](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener), by Ryan Bates, creator of the RailsCasts.

Comment: I've added "config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp" to my config/environments/development.rb file with no luck. I'm not getting any errors, and the new user is being added to the DB, just no email.

Comment: You should set `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` in your environment config to see if that gives you errors in the logs.

Comment: @mccannf, delivery errors are set to true, still nothing.

Comment: Scratch that. I reset the server and I've got it working. I think it was the "config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp". Thanks guys!

Comment: I've transformed it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the config for the environment you are trying to send emails from you might need to add `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp`.

For a complete example config using gmail see the [Rails Guides on ActionMailer (Setup with Gmail)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail).

Be sure to restart your development server after changes to config files.